# openmp argmin implementation is much slower than numpy, how do i fix this?

Tags: c, numpy, parallel-processing, openmp

So I am trying to implement numpy's argmin along an axis function in openmp. But when I test the speed of my implementation I get really really slow speeds compared to the numpy version. Do you have any idea why?

The numpy code I'm trying to implement is this :

```
res = np.array(np.argmin(distances, axis = 0))
```

distances is a n x k distance matrix. So in the openmp implementation i have find the index of the minimum value of each row and save it in res. Unfortunately I get really slow speeds. This is my openmp implementation

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>



int get_index(int x, int y, int width) { return x + (y * width); }

void execute(double *dist, int64_t *res)
{
  int n_points = 0;
  int n_k = 0;
  int i;

#pragma omp parallel
   {
    double minimum;
    int location = 0;

   #pragma omp for
    for (i = 0; i < n_points; i++)
    {
      int row_index = get_index(0, i, n_k);
      minimum = dist[row_index];
      location = 0;


      for (int j = 1; j < n_k; j++)
      {
    if (dist[row_index+j] < minimum)
    {
      minimum = dist[row_index+j];
      location = j;
    }
      }

      res[i] = location;

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the serial performance comparable to numpy? What compiler and compiler optimization options are you using?

Comment: @Elias No I see nearly no difference from when going to 1 thread, compared to 8

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - including typical input data and specific performance observations as well as a description of your system and how you compile & run the code. Also, please, format your code before posting it here.

Comment: Did you verify that your program is really running using the number of threads you wanted, for example by monitoring it using `top` while it is running?

Comment: Given that `i` is defined outside the `#pragma omp parallel` i'd be scared every thread tries to read/write for the same value. Also, what does `n_points` and `n_k` means in this context? Why not just `nRows`, `nCols` ? Seems you're overcomplicating things.